# Do I need to know SQL to learn 4D database?

Tags: 4d-database

i was offered a task in relation to 4D database, however, I do not have any database skill such as SQL, I can program but not in database aspect, just wondering should I learn some SQL before 4D database? Or are they totally different? Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4D is much more than just a [database](/questions/tagged/database); it includes a GUI designer, has it's own [programming language](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/4D-Language-Reference.100-2694908.en.html) and includes a compiler for building double-clickable applications. There are many plugins extending the product and a [plugin SDK](http://sources.4d.com/trac/4d_4dpluginapi) that allows you to write [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code to extend it yourself. The possibilities of 4D are pretty limitless. The main point here is that you could create an application that does not even use the database engine therefore database background would not be so important.

You don't need to know SQL to program in 4D.  There is a [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) layer but you can also use the non-SQL commands to achieve most of the same tasks. Granted that SQL may be better suited for some tasks, and the only option for others (see [replication and synchronization](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/Replication-via-SQL.300-2809756.en.html)). In general you should learn SQL as it will help in many different languages but don't let not knowing SQL stop you from using or learning 4D.

The 4D programming language has extensive documentation on [doc.4d.com](http://doc.4d.com):

The [4D Language Reference](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/4D-Language-Reference.100-2694908.en.html) contains the core commands

The [4D SQL reference](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/4D-SQL-Reference.100-2809640.en.html) covers the SQL aspect of the language.

The [4D Design Reference](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/4D-Design-Reference.100-2761044.en.html) covers aspects of the design environment.

There is also a [short crash course section on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4th_Dimension_(software)#Syntax) that may be helpful to give you a glimpse of the language